# Cannot arrange objects in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2015

I have a few objects in Illustrator, and I can't arrange them one behind the other.

[image]

They are both on the **same** layer. When I select one and press CTRL+SHIFT+[ the circle does not move back. When I right click I see that **Arrange** is grayed out. I tried grouping the objects together, as I saw in one solution here (though it didn't make much sense to me), and then arranging, but that didn't work either. I can arrange them in the layer panel, but it is very convoluted. Why is **Arrange** grayed out?

Comment: What if you expand the layer and try to drag these two objects into a different order in the Layers panel? Without seeing the file, it's hard to say what the problem might be. I've already exhausted all my ideas.

Comment: @joonas, I edited my question.

Comment: So let's say you start a completely new document and draw 2 objects, can you still not arrange them?

Comment: @Joonas, Yup. I can't arrange.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Have you tried to restart Illustator or [resetting preferences](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/setting-preferences.html)?

Comment: You aren't in Isolation, Draw Inside, or Draw Behind mode are you?